# Write a function to read and sum number from a file C++

Tags: c++

So the file is like this:

```
tucanos 10
tacobell 5
tucanos 5
pizzahut 15
tucanos 5
pizzahut 2
tucanos 5
```

Where the string is the restaurant's name and the number is the number of likes it has. I am supposed to find out the sum of number of likes for each restaurant from reading the file but I have no idea how to do it. Does any of you have any hints for me?

Comment: Go to google & type in "C++ file io".

Comment: where is google? since you went there and typed this I assume, why didn't you just put result here? aaaa, to make things more difficult, OK I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, here is nice function to split `std::string` into `std::vector` given a *delimiter* character:

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, 
    char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
        std::stringstream ss(s);
        std::string item;
        while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
            elems.push_back(item);
        }
        return elems;
}
```

next, we can achieve desired result using this code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::map<std::string, int> map;
    std::ifstream file("file_with_string.txt", std::ifstream::in);
    std::string temp;
    while (std::getline(file, temp)) {
        std::cout << temp << "\n";
        std::vector<std::string> tokens;
        tokens = split(temp, ' ', tokens);

        for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = tokens.begin(); 
             it != tokens.end(); it++) {
            std::vector<std::string>::iterator it1 = it;
            std::map<std::string, int>::iterator mapIt = map.find(*it++);
            int number;
            std::istringstream(*it) >> number;
            if (mapIt != map.end()) {
                (mapIt->second) += (number);
            } else {
                map[*it1] = number;
            }

        }
    }

    for (std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = map.begin(); 
         it != map.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

tucanos 10 tacobell 5 tucanos 5 pizzahut 15 tucanos 5 pizzahut 2 tucanos 5

pizzahut 17

tacobell 5

tucanos 25

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 55ms)

---

we can make it simpler

```
    std::map<std::string, int> map;
    std::ifstream infile("file_with_string.txt",std::ifstream::in);

    std::string resturant = "";
    int likes = 0;

    while(infile >> resturant >> likes ){
            map[resturant ] += likes ;
    }
```

but first version gives more insight IMO into iterators, how to traverse `std::map`, `std::vector` and how populate map.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems like the code is only usable when we know what is in the text? Sorry but I am very new to C++. Does the code still work fine if the text is unknown? As in you don't know how many lines there are, how many restaurants there are,etc.

Comment: yes. the only condition is there is convention preserved: name value

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode:

```
Open file
For each restaurant-likes pair
    Read restaurant-likes pair from file
    If first time we've seen a restaurant
        Add restaurant to list
    Lookup restaurant in list and add likes to total for that restaurant
End For
Close file

Print all restarants and total likes
```

Comment: sorry for asking another stupid question. I am thinking of using find function to find the restaurant-likes pair, but it doesn't seem to work because I don't know how many lines are there in the text. Are there any way for me to use vectors to allow for an arbitrary number of restaurant? Thanks a lot

Comment: Certainly. `std::vector`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use fscanf to parse the input from file and then apply the add operation.
[Example](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/132742-reading-numbers-file-adding-them-averaging-them.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
// c:\temp\nameofexecutable.exe < yourtextfile.txt

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string              resturant; 
    int                 likes;
    map<string, int>    likesCount;

    while (cin >> resturant >> likes) {
        likesCount[resturant] += likes;
    }

    for_each(begin(likesCount), end(likesCount),  [&](pair<string,int> x){
        cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
    }); 

    //// using plain for instead of std::for_each 
    //for (auto i = begin(likesCount); i != end(likesCount); i++)   {
    //  cout << i->first << " " << i->second << endl;
    //}


}
```

Comment: the for_each is not defined. How can I fix that?

Comment: for_each is in <algorithm> header... what compiler/ide are you using?

Comment: seen the update? instead of for_each/lambda you can use the for loop as well (the bit that is commented out)

Answer (score 0):

maybe can help you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int
main() {
        std::map<std::string, int> count;
        std::ifstream infile("cars.dat", std::ios::in);

        if (infile == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file.\n");
                exit(-1);
        }
        std::string resturant = "";
        int likes = 0;

        while(infile >> resturant >> likes ){
                count[resturant ] += likes ;
        }

        printf("--------------------each sum-------------------\n");
        std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it(count.begin());
        for (; it != sum.end(); ) {
                printf("%s %d\n", (it->first).c_str(),it->second);
                it++;
        }
        infile.close();
        return 0;

}
```

The result:
--------------------each sum-------------------
pizzahut 17
tacobell 5
tucanos 25

Comment: Thanks. But it seems like the code is only usable when we know what is in the text? Sorry but I am very new to C++. Does the code still work fine if the text is unknown? As in you don't know how many lines there are, how many restaurants there are,etc.